# Powerline network speed always slow

Tags: powerline-networking

I don't understand my Powerline network speeds.

I have the TL-WPA9610 kit, one device connected next to my router and then the WIFI one in the lounge downstairs. I also have 1 x TL-PA9020P connected in my office. Theoretical speed for all devices is 2000Mbps.

On the TP-PLC app I see all devices OK. If I look from the router's perspective I see a reported data rate of around 500Mbps to both the office and lounge.

However, when running internet speed tests I never get more than 40-50Mbps. If I'm connected over ethernet to the router, I see the full 350Mbps line speed.

I realise powerline doesn't give you close to the theoretical speeds, but I'm still only getting 10% of the reported speed.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

First of all the 2000 Mbps is marketing, real powerline PHY rate is 1800 Mbps. This is the theoretical maximum. Your real data rate depends on the distance between the adapters and on the environment. It looks like it is 500 Mbps in your case, which is a good value. This data rate is the PHY rate which is a gross data rate, the net data rate is a bit lower than half the gross data rate. So I expect about 200-250 Mbps in a speedtest.

Can you share a screenshot showing the TP-PLC app output? When interpreting it, please not that the data rates always differ between transmit and receive. So in your case you must look at the data rate from the internet to the PC. If the app shows the other direction, then that is not relevant.